# Как перевести код с Matlab на C#?

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

Здравствуйте!
Есть один довольно большой проект на MATLAB, который желательно перевести на С#

Проект написан классами, пример кода ниже, **сам код сделан похожим на шарповый.**

Я прекрасно понимаю, что надо будет расставлять типы, делать какие-то интерфейсы, что автоматизированных утилит я вряд ли найду, и что надо будет пилить это руками, но пугает объем - несколько тысяч (хз, тысячи 3-4) строк кода.

**Есть ли хотя бы какие-то конвертеры синтаксиса, чтобы не менять все эти function.... end, if... end, for... end на классический синтаксис фигурными скобками?**
Пример кода. Весь код в таком ООП стиле: класс-методы-наследование, есть ивенты

```
classdef ENode<handle

    properties
        nodes_range 
        connected_elements={};
        is_repacked=false
    end


    methods

        function copy_object=Clone(this)
            constructor=str2func(class(this));
            copy_object=constructor(this.nodes_range);
            %!!! У КОПИИ is_repacked=false!!!
        end

        function this=ENode(nodes_range)
             if nargin==1
                 this.nodes_range=nodes_range;                
             end         
        end

        function RefreshNodeRange(this,deleted_range) 
           if ~isempty(deleted_range)

                has_selfnode_deleted=false;
                new_range=this.nodes_range;
                        for i=1:length(deleted_range)
                            for j=1:length(this.nodes_range)
                                if deleted_range(i)<this.nodes_range(j)
                                    new_range(j)=new_range(j)-1;
                                elseif deleted_range(i)==this.nodes_range(j) 
                                    new_range(j)=0; 
                                    has_selfnode_deleted=true;
                                end
                            end
                        end

                        if has_selfnode_deleted 
                            k=1;
                            while 1
                                if new_range(k)==0
                                    new_range=[];
                                else
                                    k=k+1;
                                end
                                if k>length(this.nodes_range)
                                    break
                                end
                            end
                        end
                this.nodes_range=new_range;    
           end    
        end

    end
end
```

Comment: Не знаю, найдете ли Вы такую утилиту, но в первом приближении можно самому написать такую маленькую утилиту-парсер кода матлаба, которая ваши function...end, if...end и for...end будет заменять на C#-овский код. end просто заменяется на закрывающуюся фигурную скобку. С началом блока немного посложнее, но возможно.

Comment: 3-4 тысячи кода это на самом деле не так уж и много :-) Беспокоиться нужно о тех возможностях MatLab которые сложно реализовать на C# (специальные математические функции), а не `function...end` и т.д.

Comment: Конкретный вопрос в чем?

Comment: В том, как (с помощь каких инструментов лучше) сделать парсер для замены кусков матлабового синтаксиса на шарповый, главным образом это if, switch, for, while, function.  Все остальное я сделаю руками. Может быть, есть парсеры для языков с похожи синтаксисом?